# Unable to drag UI elements to Android layout Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, layout, drag-and-drop

I am having trouble getting Eclipse 4.2 to work with the latest Android SDK.  When I try to drag any of the UI elements from the palette onto the Graphical Layout of the XML, or onto the outline view, nothing happens.  Same is true when I try to drag existing elements in a relative layout.  I am able to use the XML for the layout but not the designer.

I am also not able to close tabs using the x icon, I have to right click then go to close.

I have tried using Eclipse 3.7, same problem.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved by re-downloading eclipse

Answer (score 3):

The emulator might be running. Try closing the emulator and drag ....it should work !

Answer (score 0):

Hello I am assume that into your `XML` file, You can not see the `graphical layout`. 
I have also face the same problem when I import the project from the workspace, that time simply close the project and again open the project.It works for me.

And for more Information see this [LINK](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-in-eclipse-graphical-layout-tab-does-not-appear-for-my-layout-files/)

Answer (score 0):

Check your XML for warnings displayed as little yellow exclamation marks like this one:

[image: invalid xml tag example]

Although my code was running fine this prevents any drag and drop.

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning the project and run it again. this worked for me.